# composing functions with unknown types

Tags: f#

consider this

```
let f (i : int) : string = i.ToString()
let g (s : string) : char[] = s.ToCharArray()

// we want this to be "Some (f >> g)"
let foo = Composer().Compose(f,g)
// we want this to be "None"
let bar = Composer().Compose(g,f)
```

so I want to write a 'composer' that will test the types of the functions being passed and compose or not appropriately.

A very simple brute force example that doesnt work is.

```
type Composer() = 
    member _.Compose<'a,'b,'c,'d> (f : 'a -> 'b,g : 'c -> 'd) : ('a -> 'd) option =
        match typeof<'b> = typeof<'c> with
        | true -> 
            let g1 : 'b -> 'd =
                // runtime coercion is not allowed
                // runtime type tests are not allowed on some types
                fun b -> g (b :?> 'c)
            Some (f >> g1)
        | false -> 
            None
```

It would be nice not to use brute force but I'm happy to do so.

Irritatingly this doesnt work

```
type Composer() = 
    member _.Compose<'a,'b,'c,'d> (f : 'a -> 'b,g : 'c -> 'd) : ('a -> 'd) option =
        if (g :? ('b -> 'd)) then
            Some (f >> (g :?> ('b -> 'd)))
        else 
            None
```

it says

```
the type 'c -> 'd does not have any proper subtypes and cannot 
be used as the source of a type test or runtime coercion
```

which baffles me, surely a type is trivially a subtype of itself, I cant logically see why the type system would only work if it was a 'proper' subtype

---

My confusion seems to extend to C#, or at least, the C# version of this code behaves in the way I would expect

```
    static Func<A,D>? Compose<A,B,C,D>(Func<A,B> f,Func<C,D> g)
    {
        var g1 = g as Func<B, D>;
        if (g1 == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return (A a) => g1(f(a));
        }
                
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ComposeTest()
    {
        Func<int,int> f = x => x + 1;
        Func<int, string> g = x => x.ToString();

        var foo = Compose(f,g);
        var bar = Compose(g,f);

        foo(1);
    }
```

This behaves exactly as I would expect, no 'proper subtype' error, no boxing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A slightly better answer

```
type Composer() = 
    member _.Compose<'a,'b,'c,'d> (f : 'a -> 'b,g : 'c -> 'd) : ('a -> 'd) option =
        if ((box g) :? ('b -> 'd)) then
            Some (f >> ((box g) :?> ('b -> 'd)))
        else 
            None
```

though the need to "box" g to test its type I find a little baffling.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the nuances of casting and boxed vs unboxed values but this works, it would be nice if this wasnt necessary as I know 'b is 'c, so the case is always valid

```
type Composer() = 
    member _.Compose<'a,'b,'c,'d> (f : 'a -> 'b,g : 'c -> 'd) : ('a -> 'd) option =
        match typeof<'b> = typeof<'c> with
        | true -> 
            // we want to do
            let g1 : 'b -> 'd = 
                fun b -> g (box b :?> 'c)
            Some (f >> g1)
        | false -> 
            None
```